# How can i use "str.find" (python) to locate the next character after a space or " "?

Tags: python, string, find

Its a pretty simple operation, but i cant make it work. I know there are plenty of other ways to do this and i have a working code at the moment. But since this is school related, and the teacher asks specifically for str.find i have to make it work his way.

My code at the moment:

```
def initialer(name):
    forname =[0]
    space = name.find(" ")
    surname = ???
    return initialer

print initialer("Andy Olsen")
```

My working code, but not accepted for this assignment:

```
def initialer(name):
    x = name.split(" ")
    y = [words[0] for words in x]
    return ".".join(y) + "."
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: what's the `forname =[0]` and `surname = ???` and `return initialer` for in your first code snippet?

Comment: there are so many errors in your code at the moment ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only two words:

```
def initialer(name):
    space_pos = name.find(' ')
    if space_pos == -1:
        return name[0]
    else:
        return name[0] + name[space_pos + 1]
```

Multiple words:

```
def initialer(name):
    space_pos = name.find(' ')
    if space_pos == -1:
        return name[0]
    else:
        return name[0] + initialer(name[space_pos + 1:])
```

More pythonic:

```
def initialer(name, splitter=' '):
    words = name.split(splitter)
    return u''.join(zip(*words)[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my_str = "hello world!"
print my_str[my_str.find(" ") + 1]
```